# What is the best way to implement preventing user from logging in for a certain amount of time after 5 failed login attempts?

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo

I am developing a react native application and I am wondering how should the state for the logged user be persisted after 5 failed attempts?

For example, is it okay to save this in AsyncStorage and add a count down timer etc and load this value when the app starts to see whether should the application be locked?